# How to remove a total in a Stacked Bar Graph in Power BI

Tags: powerbi-desktop

How to remove a total in a Stacked Bar Graph in Microsoft Power BI?

I am using the Desktop version.

Se the attached image. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

If you select data on in the left side panel and select the dataset you are working on in your Stacked Bar Graph. Next step is to select the column you do not want to summarize and then click "Do not summarize" ind the top bar.